# Android: view data binding to boolean live data

Tags: android, mvvm

I have a view model that looks a bit like this:

```
class MenuViewModel(
    val state :MutableLiveData<StateModel?> = MutableLiveData()
) : ViewModel() {

    val hasUserProfileUrl
        get() = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().also {
            it.addSource(state, Observer {
                null != it?.userProfileUrl
            })
        }
}
```

And a view with this XML:

```
        <Button
                style="@style/MenuButton"
                android:text="Share profile link"
                android:visibility="@{ model.hasUserProfileUrl }" />
```

And the following binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
fun setVisibility(view: View, value: Boolean?) {
    view.setVisibility(if (true == value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
}
```

How ever my button is always hidden. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (true == value)`

Replace this above check with below:

`if (value)`

Comment: @MuhammadAwais I'm afraid that doesn't make any difference